# How to Use Django Rest Framework to Call API with Javascript Files

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I've done a  few projects in Django before but I've never done one using the Django Rest framework, and it's my first time using an API.

I'm trying to learn how to use it, and the class I'm taking makes it mandatory to create the project in Django, and use Javascript as the front end.

2 Questions:

I'd like to call the API within the Javascript code. Can this be done using the Django Rest framework?

I'm also having trouble figuring out how to show my html file with this url setup. Any help is appreciated. Currently when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ I just get the API Root page.

So far most tutorials I see, are just for calling the API in a Django view. They don't talk about how to use Javascript files to call the API also with the Django Rest Framework, and show the html file to the user. If you can point me to documentation or explain a bit more I'd really appreciate it!

views.py - currently the home view is not showing or doing anything, but I want this to show to the user.

```
class LocationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Location.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer()

def home(request):
    return render(request, "capstone/home.html")
```

capstone/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'locations', views.LocationViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("temp", views.temp, name="temp"), 
   ]
```

weather/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('capstone.urls')), # medium site says to do this
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the API root page when you visit "/" because you have two urls for same path

```
path('', include(router.urls)),
path("", views.home, name="home")
```

It is first matched with `router.urls` that's why it is going to api root page. If you want to get home page on "/" then change the first url.

Also you make use of API from Javascript by using something as [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Also I think you need to learn bit more about DRF before jumping into the project. You can check documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/). You can also learn from youtube, there are a bunch of good content teaching you about DRF.